# How can Amazon RDS grant CREATE EXTENSION to their RDS_SUPERUSER role?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I've been trying for some time to allow ordinary, non-superuser users to create extensions.

While reading across RDS documentation, I find that their internal "master user", rds_superuser, is capable of creating extensions, even though it is not an actual superuser, as is well documented.

Further searching leads me to [this table](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html):

```
|Database Engine|System privilege|Database role|
|---------------|----------------|-------------|
|PostgreSQL     |`CREATE ROLE, CREATE DB, PASSWORD VALID UNTIL INFINITY, CREATE EXTENSION, ALTER EXTENSION, DROP EXTENSION, CREATE TABLESPACE, ALTER < OBJECT> OWNER, CHECKPOINT, PG_CANCEL_BACKEND(), PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND(), SELECT PG_STAT_REPLICATION, EXECUTE PG_STAT_STATEMENTS_RESET(), OWN POSTGRES_FDW_HANDLER(), OWN POSTGRES_FDW_VALIDATOR(), OWN POSTGRES_FDW, EXECUTE PG_BUFFERCACHE_PAGES(), SELECT PG_BUFFERCACHE`|RDS_SUPERUSER
```

When I try executing `grant create extension to` any user, I get a syntax error.

How is this grant possible?

Comment: RDS is not a vanilla postgresql. This is a closed fork with several code modifications. They could replace the "!superuser()" check with their RDS_SUPERUSER role membership without introducing separate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE EXTENSION` is *not* a grantable privilege. It is hard-coded who can create extensions.

In PostgreSQL, this is restricted to superusers, and from v13 on to users with the `CREATE` privileges on the database (if the extension is a "trusted" one).

Note, however, that RDS is different from PostgreSQL, and <strike>god</strike>Jeff only knows how they hacked up the code.